# jQuery .change() function bind to select doesn't work ( inside Smarty template)

Tags: jquery, smarty, prestashop

I've got the following problem.
On the e-commerce website (made with Prestashop, so it uses Smarty), products sorting doesn't work. It's a SELECT field, which is changed dynamically when user selects some option (site reloads). Please look at the following code:

First, Smarty:

```
{if isset($orderby) AND isset($orderway)}
<!-- Sort products -->
{if isset($smarty.get.id_category) && $smarty.get.id_category}
    {assign var='request' value=$link->getPaginationLink('category', $category, false, true)}
{elseif isset($smarty.get.id_manufacturer) && $smarty.get.id_manufacturer}
    {assign var='request' value=$link->getPaginationLink('manufacturer', $manufacturer, false, true)}
{elseif isset($smarty.get.id_supplier) && $smarty.get.id_supplier}
    {assign var='request' value=$link->getPaginationLink('supplier', $supplier, false, true)}
{else}
    {assign var='request' value=$link->getPaginationLink(false, false, false, true)}
{/if}
```

Then, jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
{literal}
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#selectPrductSort').change(function()
    {
        var requestSortProducts = '{/literal}{$request}{literal}';
        var splitData = $(this).val().split(':');
        document.location.href = requestSortProducts + ((requestSortProducts.indexOf('?') < 0) ? '?' : '&') + 'orderby=' + splitData[0] + '&orderway=' + splitData[1];
    });
});
//]]>
{/literal}
</script>
```

And HTML:

```
<form id="productsSortForm" action="{$request|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">
    <p class="select">
        <label for="selectPrductSort">{l s='Sortuj wg'}&nbsp;</label>
        <select id="selectPrductSort">
            <option value="{$orderbydefault|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}:{$orderwaydefault|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if $orderby eq $orderbydefault}selected="selected"{/if}>{l s='--'}</option>
            {if !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                <option value="price:asc" {if $orderby eq 'price' AND $orderway eq 'asc'}selected="selected"{/if}>{l s='ceny - od najniższej'}</option>
                <option value="price:desc" {if $orderby eq 'price' AND $orderway eq 'desc'}selected="selected"{/if}>{l s='ceny - od najwyższej'}</option>
            {/if}
            <option value="name:asc" {if $orderby eq 'name' AND $orderway eq 'asc'}selected="selected"{/if}>{l s='nazwy produktu - od A do Z'}</option>
            <option value="name:desc" {if $orderby eq 'name' AND $orderway eq 'desc'}selected="selected"{/if}>{l s='nazwy produktu - od Z do A'}</option>
            {if !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                <option value="quantity:desc" {if $orderby eq 'quantity' AND $orderway eq 'desc'}selected="selected"{/if}>{l s='dostępności'}</option>
            {/if}
        </select>
    </p>
</form>
```

Under this link - http://skleppatrioty.pl/category.php?id_category=5 - you can see a working example. It's a SELECT field, next to the text "Sortuj wg", in the upper part of the main, right column.

Am I missing something? Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you tell a little about the error(s) you're getting?

Comment: Well, Firebug gives 2 errors: "1. NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://skleppatrioty.pl/modules/maofree_blockcarousel/css/blockcarousel_css.php" 2. TypeError: $(".blockcarousel .jCarouselLite").jCarouselLite is not a function" However, I am not sure if this has something to do with the problem, because on the localhost there are no Firebug errors, and sorting still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the live site and the above code looks fine.

I recommend getting rid of the carousel error first.